# Read attribute of a parent/ancestor node using xpath axes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to read the 'division' attribute of 'class' node from 'student' node using XPath & XSLT.

```
<class division="myDiv">
    <student rollno="700">
        <firstname>Renjith</firstname>
        <lastname>R</lastname>
        <nickname>Renju</nickname>
        <marks>70</marks>
    </student>
    <student rollno="493">
        <firstname>fname1</firstname>
        <lastname>lname1</lastname>
        <nickname>nick1</nickname>
        <marks>95</marks>
    </student>
</class>
```

my condition is, if the firstname is 'Renjith', read the 'division' attribute of 'class' node, which i believe is a parent node of student node.

i used the following xpath to check if the first name is 'Renjith'

```
//student[firstname/text() = 'Renjith']
```

I am at student node whose first name is 'Renjith'.Now i need to get the value of division attribute from 'class' node, who is the parent of student node.
i could achieve the result using the following xpath expressions.

```
1)parent::class/@division
or
2)ancestor::class/@division
```

I got two questions here.
1. what is the difference b/w expressions 1 & 2?
2. is there any way i could get the 'division' attribute with out specifying the parent node name 'class'?
I know '`../@division`' can do the trick. but my intention is to study the xpath axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`..` is a shortcut for `parent::node()` so `parent::node()/@division` is the verbose way of using the parent axis, if you insist on doing it that way. As for `ancestor::class`, if you had nested `<class><class><student>..</student></class></class>` elements (which semantically probably does not make sense for your data but is possible in general in XML) then `ancestor::class selects both ancestor`class`elements while`parent::class`selects only the parent`class`.